# Add text to richbox without deleting

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, checkbox, console

i try to mekae a program how tell me in a richbox what i do for examle, i have 4 CheckBoxes when i click one enable in RichBox must apear
apple enabled...
pear disabled...
So i have apple pear carrot peanut
and richbox need look like,

Pear disabled...
Carrot disabled...
Peanut Enabled...
Pear Enabled....
SUBMIT SUCCES !
Pear disabled...
I try that for every checkbox but when i check one richbox is reset and apear only one line

```
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = "pear enabled..."
    Else
        RichTextBox1.Text = "pear disabled..."
    End If
```

What can i do ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need this:

```
If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
    RichTextBox1.Text &= "pear enabled..." & Environment.NewLine()
Else
    RichTextBox1.Text &= "pear disabled..." & Environment.NewLine()
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the SelectedText property of the Rich Text Box control to append text properly. Please see the following code..

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If (CheckBox1.Checked) Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = CheckBox1.Text & " Enabled" & vbCrLf
    Else
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = CheckBox1.Text & " Disabled" & vbCrLf
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    If (CheckBox1.Checked) Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = CheckBox2.Text & " Enabled" & vbCrLf
    Else
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = CheckBox2.Text & " Disabled" & vbCrLf
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
    If (CheckBox1.Checked) Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = CheckBox2.Text & " Enabled" & vbCrLf
    Else
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = CheckBox2.Text & " Disabled" & vbCrLf
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for is "append" text.

RichTextBox1.AppendText("pear enabled...")